# Inserting in SQLite database from file, only one row inserted

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I'm inserting rows in android SQLite database from a file. In the onUpdate function in the databaseHelper I call the insertInDb function:

```
InputStream is = null;
AssetManager assetManager = context.getResources().getAssets();
String fileLine = "";
String[] data;
ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
long rowid;

try {
    is = assetManager.open(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    db.beginTransaction();
    while((fileLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        data = fileLine.split("@-@");
        row.put(QuoteAllEntry.COLUMN_QUOTE, data[0]);
        row.put(QuoteAllEntry.COLUMN_AUTHOR, data[1]);
        row.put(QuoteAllEntry.COLUMN_FAVORITE, 0);
        row.put(QuoteAllEntry.COLUMN_CAT_KEY, data[2]));
        rowid = db.insert(DataContract.QuoteAllEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, row);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Only one row of data is inserted, and it is the last row of the file. What is going wrong? I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: No exception is fired? Also can you put the file you are using. Especially the first lines where process breaks?

Comment: *Only one row of data is inserted, and it is the last row of the file* ... **then the file has only one row** ... `db.setTransactionSuccessful();` is last and without this the data would not be added ... but last is added so there was no exception inside try ... so ... there is no other possibility than having only one row in the file

Comment: there is a good chance that changing the `row` object after you passed it to the db object is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Move `ContentValues row = new ContentValues();` inside the while-loop.

Also you're not closing the input stream which results in memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard pattern for transactions, move `setTransactionSuccessful()` inside while loop

```
beginTransaction();
try {
//db operations ...

setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: db.setTransactionSuccessful(); is inside the try {} but not inside the while loop. Somehow only one row is inserted in the database and I can't seem to figure out why.